# Possible to stubbing a response’s body with Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, cypress

With Puppeteer, we can intercept XHR responses and read the content. My question is if it's possible to manipulate the response to be whatever we want it to be and use the changed data when the page is rendered.

Example of intercepting a response with Puppeteer:

```
page.on("response", (response) => {

});
```

With Cypress, we can modify the response by providing our own data to the object that we pass to cy.route():

```
cy.server()           // enable response stubbing
cy.route({
  method: 'GET',      // Route all GET requests
  url: '/users/*',    // that have a URL that matches '/users/*'
  response: []        // and force the response to be: []
})
```

Can the same thing be achieved with Puppeteer?

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Routing

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.0.1&show=api-requestresponse):

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
  request.respond({
    status: 404,
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    body: "Here we can provide our own mock"
  });
});
```